# base.OnPaint order changes drawing location

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a strange problem. I made my own user control deriving from `UserControl`. I override `OnPaint`. Now I draw something in `OnPaint`. Let's say at position 0, 0.

If I call `base.OnPaint` after my custom drawing everything is fine. But if I call `base.OnPaint` before the stuff I'm drawing, it seems to ignore the containing control and the location is relative to the form instead of relative to the client area of the parent control. So when I draw at position (0, 0) it will effectively be drawn at negative x and y and I will only see a part of it. The `base.OnPaint` is `UserControl.OnPaint`. So I don't call my code there.

Here is an example:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaint(e);

    var rect = new System.Drawing.Rectangle(this.ClientSize.Width - 16,
            this.ClientSize.Height - 16, 16, 16);

    e.Graphics.FillRectangle(new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(System.Drawing.Color.Red), rect);

    //base.OnPaint(e);
}
```

In this case the red rectangle is displayed somewhere inside the client area but not at the lower right corner. If I uncomment the last line and comment the first line the red rectangle is displayed at the lower right corner as expected.

I don't get it. I did this many times and it always worked. So I tried to find any differences. The only I found is that I don't add my control in the designer but add it programmatically to another control with `theContainingControl.Controls.Add(myMessedUpControl);`.

This also happens for every parent-child-level I add. So if I create another control (another class) and also override `OnPaint` the behavior is the same if I add it to another user control.

Does anyone had this behavior before? How can I fix this? The problem is that I want to call `base.OnPaint` first and also everyone suggest this. But as I said I can't without messing the coordinates up.

One note: The coordinates are really 0, 0 in the debugger at the draw calls like `DrawLine`, `DrawImage` oder `DrawString`. But the result is displayed at negative coordinates (relative to the client area). It looks like the client coordinates are interpreted as client coordinates of the form. But I don't know why.

**Found the problem**

In my project there is a graphical overlay class which connects `Paint` event handlers to all controls in my form (the whole hierarchy). In this handler a transformation is performed. This graphical overlay kept me sleepless so many times. I guess I will remove it.

Comment: FillRectangle with a Brush and an integer only?

Comment: `FillRectangle(brush , 16)`? How can `16` be a ractangle?

Comment: Sorry pasted wrong code. Updated.

Comment: The only task of `base.OnPaint` in a `UserControl` is raising `Paint` event. So the order of your painting and calling `base.OnPaint` is not important in this case. So the current code doesn't reproduce the problem. Please consider [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Reza Aghaei: This is the problem. It works with minimal codes and my current project is to large to break it down to something. As Luaan suggested `ResetTransform` helps but I don't get where the transformation was changed as I don't have any such calls in my entire code.

Comment: It's really good that the Luaan's suggestion helped you to solve the problem, but you should find the root cause of the problem. Also your current question doesn't share anything about a control hierarchy and you posted a code and stated that you have derived from `UserControl`. So the best thing that could be said about this case was what I said in comment :)

Comment: I appreciate your help. And I also want to find the root cause of the problem. Unfortunately I spent many hours on it and still have no clue. Moreover my time to find the cause is very limited now as I have to finish lots of other stuff. My bet is still the `Region` property. This is the only thing I change which could affect transformation imho. I hope I'll find the time to investigate more on this and can provide the root cause to help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Graphics` object has a lot of mutable state. The order of operations matters if you mess with this mutable state - for example, you can use the `Transform` matrix to change the offset of everything rendered on the surface.

It sounds like your ascendant changes one of those during its own `OnPaint` handler without resetting it back. Try doing a `e.Graphics.ResetTransform();` before you start your own painting. Make sure all the other state is also the way you want it (clip, DPI, ...).

Comment: `ResetTransform` did the trick. I just don't get it where the graphics object is changed. It must happen outside of the paint event as I only call `UserControl.OnPaint`. I also do no transformations at all. The only things in my own code are draw calls. I bet it has to do with `Control.Region` which I modify frequently (but outside of the paint event).

Comment: Moreover the drawing works in designer. The transformation is only messed up at runtime. So I think it really is the changing of `Control.Region` at some events.

Comment: @RoberS. Well, the whole window model of Windows is very complicated. If you want to really understand what's happening, I'm afraid there's no shortcut but to learn how the window model works - all the nitty gritty of WM_PAINT and the other paint events, GDI, surfaces, composition etc. Also, note that the base `OnPaint` handler on `Control` will invoke the `Paint` event handlers - are you sure there are none? That part isn't executed in the designer either.

Comment: I also thought of the `Paint` event handler but I checked and there are none. I know the window model a fair bit. I worked with the WinAPI many ages ago. My problem are special cases and .NET properties with side effects. I found some control properties which seem to just hold a single value but changing or even reading them start a bunch of low-level routines in the background. I guess something like that is the problem here.

Comment: You were right. It was a `Paint` event handler. This one was attached at the form level by going through the whole control hierarchy. So I didn't noticed it.